# What is the syntax and correct way of using SourceBaby, one of the bots used in the Perl 6 related channels?

Tags: raku, whateverable

SourceBaby is apparently one of the Whateverable bots, running in the #perl6 and other IRC channels, which is able to [locate the source of Perl 6 functions](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2018-05-22#i_16194214). However, the syntax is kind of difficult to figure out. To locate `lazy-if`, which is a method of `Any`, you have to do (like in the link).

```
s: Any, "lazy-if", \(1)
```

I have been trying to google for instructions, but I just couldn't find them. [It's not in the official list of Whateverable bots, either](https://github.com/perl6/whateverable/wiki). Anyone can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It's not in the official list of Whateverable bots, either.

That's 'cause it's not a Whateverable bot. There are several other community bots that aren't Whateverables, including `huggable` and `buggable` bots.

Asking the bot for help gives you a hint where to look for:

```
<Zoffix>    SourceBaby: help
<SourceBaby>    Zoffix, Use s: trigger with args to give to sourcery
    sub. e.g. s: Int, 'base'. 
    See http://modules.perl6.org/dist/CoreHackers::Sourcery
```

The [`CoreHackers::Sourcery`](http://modules.perl6.org/dist/CoreHackers::Sourcery) module is just a thin wrapper around core functionality of `Code` object's [`.file`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Code#method_file) and [`.line`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Code#method_line) methods. They report the location of routine's definitions for all routines and for core routines they have this special `SETTING::` string that shows the location in [`rakudo`'s](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/) source (or whatever compiler you're using):

```
say "{.file}:{.line}" with Any.^lookup: "lazy-if"
# SETTING::src/core/Any.pm6:472
```

And the bot is a thin wrapper around [`CoreHackers::Sourcery`](http://modules.perl6.org/dist/CoreHackers::Sourcery)'s [`sourcery` routine](https://github.com/zoffixznet/perl6-CoreHackers-Sourcery#subroutines). And that's all you do when triggering the bot. You're literally typing arbitrary Perl 6 code that will be inserted as args into that routine and then evaled.

The two calling forms are:

```
:(Callable:D \to-lookup, Capture \args?) 
:(Mu \object, Str:D \method-name, Capture \args?)
```

The first one is a 1-2 arg form that you'd usually use with subroutines:

```
<Zoffix> s: &say
<SourceBaby> Zoffix, Sauce is at https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/d1d31fd57/src/core/io_operators.pm6#L10
```

And the second one is a 2-3 arg form that you'd usually use with methods on objects:

```
<Zoffix> s: $*ERR, 'print'
<SourceBaby> Zoffix, Sauce is at https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/d1d31fd57/src/core/IO/Handle.pm6#L604
```

The last arg in both forms is a `Capture` of arguments that you want to call the callable with. It's optional, in which case you'd get a proto's location for multi routines. So usually you'd specify the args to get a specific candidate's location:

```
<Zoffix> s: $*ERR, 'print', \(1, 2, 3)
<SourceBaby> Zoffix, Sauce is at https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/d1d31fd57/src/core/IO/Handle.pm6#L609
```

Comment: I've long been bemused by SourceBaby. I've never been motivated enough to read and understand the help. With this answer it all looks so simple and perfect. Thanks for this useful bot (in principle), it's nice design (in practice), and this excellent explanation (making it easy for me). Your persistent productivity and patience is very inspiring.